# How to save the access token in php?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am using this endpoint to get the long-lived token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

But I want to know how can I get it with php.

I need to use the curl library ? 
Or is there a simplest solution ?

Comment: You should take a look into the SDK https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Comment: there is nothing about how to retrieve the long-lived token.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple curl function to use with the facebook sdk. Don't forget to change the path to the `fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt`.

```
function curl($url, $certificate = false) {

    $c = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/sdk/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt');

    $output = curl_exec($c);

    if ($output === false) {
        curl_close($c);
        return false;
    }

    curl_close($c);
    return $output;

}
```

And here is the method call to get the long lived token:

```
§token = curl('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.
               $app_id.'&client_secret='.
               $app_secret.'&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token='.
               $api->getAccessToken());
```

Comment: glad i could help you. to support the thought of stackoverflow and give back to the community you could accept some answers given to your questions.